# How to understand "has, so far, been unascertainable" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, prepositions

This comes from "The history of western philosophy" by Bertrand Russell.
"Like theology, it consists of speculations on matters as to which definite knowledge has, so far, been unascertainable." What confuses me is "has, so far, been unascertainable", what is the subject of the **has** here? And how to understand **as to which**?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because mistakes happen.

Comment: @YosefBaskin: Am I missing something? I see no "mistakes" - just Russell being a bit "verbose" and "convoluted", as usual. (Though I will admit I really don't like ***as to*** there, and would much prefer ***regarding*** myself.)

Comment: The OP wrote a comment of mistaking "definite" for *define*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Knowledge* has so far been unascertainable.

“As to which” means “regarding which” (matters)